# Trying to execute a script with WSL, but it doesn't do execute anything after the `bash` command

Tags: bash, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have this batch script that I can successfully run by copy-pasting into a command prompt. It starts with `bash` which launches WSL and then contains the rest of the batch script. When I run the script as a .cmd file it doesn't do anything past this [image: Doesn't continue with script execution]

The rest of the script is never executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is 100% normal. When a script contains a command that isn't backgrounded, it starts that command, and then waits for the command to exit before it does anything else. So if your script runs `bash`, it won't do anything else (won't run any subsequent commands) until bash exits.

Comment: ...if your script were _written in bash_, I'd tell you to to pass contents you wanted it to run as a heredoc, but if this is a cmd script, you need people who are cmd.exe experts to tell you what the local equivalent to a heredoc is, if there even exists such a thing.

Comment: Or you could just put the bash parts of the script in a separate file, and instead of running `bash`, run `bash thatfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Windows VM available with me so cannot test but my understanding is cmd executes command one by one so next command after bash will only execute after the first one successfully completes.

If what i say above is true then if you exit from the bash command then you will see you rest of the commands being executed one by one

Now to coming to the solution of this problem if you have bash script to run then

```
bash -c "~/myscript.sh"
```

or

```
bash -c "command"
```

this should do the job